# How to create my own PHP magic method names?

Tags: php, magic-methods

Some frameworks have their own magic methods names, such as

```
$player->findByName('Lionel Messi')
```

which results in a simple `SELECT * FROM players WHERE name='Lionel Messi'` query. In PHP how can I make similar methods? Do they somehow catch the global `MethodNotFoundException`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: BTW, I find this often to be misguided. In the end you'll have a finite amount of different kinds of queries you'll have to do. Being able to automagically generate queries through syntactic sugar has a diminishing point of return, once you have written all the possible `findByX` calls you'll ever need. That's when such a system can become a burden, because you have no real inventory of all your possible calls and cannot optimise or refactor easily. In other words: I prefer to define my `findByX` methods by hand one by one, it's really not much of a problem.

Comment: I see your point, although I wont be changing the db structure, as this project where I plan to implement this little syntactic sugar is my own. So I can avoid deep refactoring, needs wont just change. :)

Comment: May I come back in two years to ask you whether your needs have changed...? ;-P

Comment: of course, I'll be sitting here waiting :D

Comment: @deceze Time flies, right? :) I've used `__call()` very little since then. For later projects I've moved to more profound design patterns, in which you don't need such hacks if properly designing the underlying class structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `__call` magic method.
Read more about it in docs, that is all you need.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

```
public function __call($name, $args) {
    // TODO: Parse called method name and run query if needed
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this will be it :)

Comment: Why would `findByName` ever be a magic method? It just makes no sense at all.

Comment: it's a magic method name, not a magic method, OK now?

Comment: BTW it's commonly referred as magic method name in the framework world, I read the same terminology in both CakePHP and Laravel docs.

Comment: No not OK. It makes no sense. Can you link to an example because I get a feeling this is not what you are looking for

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby

Comment: Also have a blink at Eloquent ORM: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes the `whereGender()` part

Comment: Holy **** that is bad :| ok didn't say anything about actual usage. I see, but if you are sane you don't use it :P